# Как задать имя файловому полю Dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, dropzone

Есть задача с помощью библиотеки Dropzone.js сделать прикрепление файлов к существующей форме. То-есть без фоновой отправки картинок, просто добавить картинки к форме после загрузки этих картинок. Почти всё получилось, кроме присвоение имени полю `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="dz-hidden-input" accept="image/*" tabindex="-1" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">`, которое Dropzone добавляем автоматически.

Прошу помочь разобраться как это сделать. Предоставляю код:

```
// Меняем шаблон превью загруженных картинок
var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
previewNode.id = "";
var previewTemplate = previewNode.innerHTML;
previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

/*Загрузка картинок*/
new Dropzone("#contacts-form", {
    //url: window.location.origin + "/contacts/add",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    paramName: "images", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    addRemoveLinks: false,
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB,
    maxFiles: 6,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
    clickable: ".fileinput-button",
    autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
    hiddenInputContainer: "#contacts-form" // В форму добавляемся поле input type="file"
    ...
});
```

По итогу к форме `#contacts-form` добавляется `input` для загрузки файлов, но у него нет прааметра `name`. Не нашел в документации как можно его добавить. Есть ли нативный способ это сделать?

(В форме не забыл указать `enctype="multipart/form-data"`)

Comment: т.е. вы хотите добавить имя инпуту для добавления стилей ему? или для чего?

Comment: Имя инпуту мне нужно чтобы картинки отправлялись в этом инпуте вместе с моей формой. То-есть просто прикрепить загруженные картинки к моей форме, а не фоново отправлять их отдельно.

Answer (score 2):

Используй коллбэк init, чтобы получить доступ к скрытому input файлов через свойство this.hiddenFileInput и установи нужное имя с помощью setAttribute().
Если я правильно понимаю, также можно задать имя при инициализации Dropzone:
hiddenInputName: "FileName"
Это установит нужное имя для скрытого input автоматически.

Comment: Параметр `hiddenInputName` при инициализации не помогает. Такого нет ни в документации, ни в исходниках библиотеки. Я смотрел, она создает поле без имени из коробки. Настроить его нельзя.

По поводу коллбека `init` - я не понимаю где нужно это прописать. Пробывал через:

    `this.on("addedfile", file => {`
        `this.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("name", "images[]");`
    `});`

Оно вроде как добавляет имя полю, но потом библиотека `dropzone` его снова переписывет и оно опть без имени.

Comment: Или так: const myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myForm", {

  init: () => {

    myDropzone.on("addedfile", () => {
      myDropzone.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("name", "myImages"); 
    });

  }

});       Или без init: const myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myForm");

myDropzone.on("addedfile", () => {
  myDropzone.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("name", "myImages");
});